# How do I open a relative path under the cursor

Tags: vimscript, functions, open

I often have file log where there are several relative path to files. The paths are relative to the location of the filelog. My understanding is that I'm able to open the relative path if the CWD of vim contain that relative path. Is there a way to automatically compose the path for gf (goto file) to prepend the absolute path of the filelog opened to the relative path in it ?

Comment: Not sure. I've just checked. If I open an absolute path with vim (e.g. `/home/user1/path1/file.log`) while i'm in a completely different path (e.g. `/etc/path2/path3`), when I do :pwd i get  `/etc/path2/path3`, and not `/home/user1/path1/`. All the file in file.log are relative to `/home/user1/path1/` and if I try to open vim doesn't find them. Is there something wrong in my vim settings ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to change the path with `:lcd` and maybe try to think a function to do it.

Comment: It's possible you have non-default settings that interfere with the behavior. Try the same steps but without your vimrc file (you can run vim with `--clean` flag, for instance).

Comment: I start to think that maybe I'm using a way too old version of vim, it doesn't recognize the `--clean` option and the version is : `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 12 2016 09:49:04)`

Comment: So I tried `-u NONE` and `:pwd` is still returning the path where I executed vim and not the path where the file I opened is. I loaded a newer version of vim (8.2) and I still have the same behavior. If I do a `:pwd` after  `:lcd` to the path I want, I can see the right value returned by `:pwd` set (the one set by :lcd`).

Comment: Can you try with `--clean`? This loads known default settings. I'll investigate what settings might be messing with this behavior. Actually I just tried with `-u NONE` and everything still works fine.

Comment: Yeah, with the 8.2 I tried `--clean` and it still doesn't work. Might it be a compilation setting ? Just to clarify I'm working on a cluster and I don't have any control on how and what it is installed/compiled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120912/discussion-between-b-layer-and-haster8558).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on (my reading of) your description...

- You edit file `/foo/bar/baz.log`
- In `baz.log` are relative paths like `quux/this.txt`
- `quux` is a subdirectory of `/foo/bar`

If I've interpreted things correctly then `gf` with your cursor over `quux/this.txt` should open `this.txt` without any other steps.

That is, unless you've modified `'path'`. It should contain `.` (dot meaning current directory). This setting influences how `gf` works.

Comment: @haster8558 Though the topic of  'current file vs current working directory' didn't end up having any bearing on things you may be interested in this:  [Set working directory to the current file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file) . (The reason I thought this was the default behavior is that I completely forgot that I have `autocmd BufEnter * if expand("%:p:h") !~ '^/tmp' | silent! lcd %:p:h | endif` in my vimrc. It's been in there for years.)